# How to find dates between two dates excluding start and end date using python

Tags: python

I have two dates `10-02-2016` and `16-02-2016` in `dd-mm-yyyy` format, I want the list of dates between those dates without including start and end date.

**Expected output:**

```
11-02-2016
12-02-2016
13-02-2016
14-02-2016
15-02-2016
```

I have the following code snippet:

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('10-02-2016', '%d-%m-%Y').date()
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('16-02-2016', '%d-%m-%Y').date()

delta = date2 - date1
for i in range(delta.days):
    print(date1 + datetime.timedelta(i))
```

Which gives output as:

```
10-02-2016
11-02-2016
12-02-2016
13-02-2016
14-02-2016
15-02-2016
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use list comprehension slicing the first element.

Comment: You can change `range(1,delta.days+1)`. This will start the loop with `i=1` instead of `i=0`.

Comment: Thanks @TylerChen, It works fine.

Comment: @TylerChen, `range(1,delta.days)` is more close, because OP does not need the last one.

Comment: `range(1, delta.days)` it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

date1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('10-02-2016', '%d-%m-%Y').date()
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('16-02-2016', '%d-%m-%Y').date()

delta = date2 - date1
for i in range(1,delta.days):
    print(date1 + datetime.timedelta(i))
```

Comment: this is the best one

Answer (score 1):

Option with list comprehension, slice where you need:

```
list_of_dates = [ date1 + datetime.timedelta(i) for i in range((date2 - date1).days + 1) ]

for date in list_of_dates[1:-1]:
  print(date)

# 2016-02-11
# 2016-02-12
# 2016-02-13
# 2016-02-14
# 2016-02-15
```